# Why is Java Logging API not displaying FINE messages?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I am wondering why Java Logging API is not displaying fine, finer, and finest messages.

Let's look at the following code:

```
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
logger.info("Level:" + logger.getLevel());
logger.severe("Some Fatal message%n");
logger.warning("Some WARN message%n");
logger.info("Some INFO message%n");
logger.fine("Some DEBUG message%n");
logger.finer("Some DEBUG message%n");
logger.finest("Some TRACE message%n");
```

I would expect this to display every log message, since I am specifying LogLevel.ALL in the first line.

However it is omitting the fine messages, this is what I see:

22-08-28 16:37:25.997 INFO    [global] Level:ALL
22-08-28 16:37:26.025 SEVERE  [global] Some Fatal message
22-08-28 16:37:26.025 WARNING [global] Some WARN message
22-08-28 16:37:26.026 INFO    [global] Some INFO message

Why is it skipping the fine, finer, and finest, given that I have the level set to ALL?

Comment: Those if-statements are useless by the way. Check the implementation of those methods. They already call `isLoggable` themselves. Adding the condition yourself is worse in 3 ways: verbosity, performance, and susceptibility to typo bugs.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that, removed. Is that true for other logging frameworks as well, such as Log4J 1/2, Logback and SLF4J, etc?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that the logger is responsible for deciding if the message should be logged based on the message's level and the configured level of the logger. Application code should not be concerned with that. Pretty much the only time it makes sense to manually check if a logger will log at a certain level is if the message is expensive to compute, but most (if not all) modern frameworks provide an API to specify lazily computed messages.

Comment: It's true for all those frameworks, yes. There are some exceptions when you might want to include the condition, like `log.debug("foo {}", someExpensiveOperation())` but it's not the norm

Comment: With `java.util.logging`, the `Handler`s also have a level that you need to configure. Also, depending on how you got the instance of `logger`, it's possible it has no handlers, and in fact the output you're seeing is from one of its ancestors (assuming `useParentHandlers` is not set to `false`).

Comment: @Michael But even then, you could do `log.debug("foo {}", () -> someExpensiveOperation())` or something similar, without the manual if-can-log-at-certain-level condition check, at least with Log4j2's API.

Answer (score 2):

You need to additionally set the level on the [Handlers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Handler.html). Handlers are the things which take the actual log events and then push them to stdout, in your case.

```
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
for (Handler handler : logger.getParent().getHandlers()) {
    handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
}
```

Comment: I have the following line in my config file. Should that not do the trick? java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=FINEST

Comment: @VictorGrazi Well where are you looking for the logs? You never stated. If you're looking in the *console* then no. In future please include all details like this in the original question.